# Weird glitch image on google maps infowindow with bootstrap

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

[image]

As you can see there is a glitch image right underneath the infowindow, the black shadow. 
There is another glitch located in the zoom in and zoom out button. 
I'm using bootstrap. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to the css of the div containing the map

```
        #MapDiv img { 
           max-width: none; 
        }
```

Comment: Awesome - you saved some time and headache!