# google maps api v3 infowindow class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, gmaps4rails2

Using the gmaps4rails v2 gem... I have a map going.  The CSS is a bit off for it, and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to target a specific div **in** the map to either add a class, or change the styling.

[image]

So, I know which div I have to adjust... and I was able to add `border-radius` and change the `height` from 94 to 96.  I just don't know how to select it...

If it helps... the div directly beneath the div I need to select is the div that has the actual infowindow information in it.

**Update** As for part of the issue... Methinks bootstrap is playing a role:

```
media="all"
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: There must be another way to do this. You could target those divs and pick the one that has the index you want but I don't know if that remains the same. Maybe infobox could work for you?

Comment: I was really hoping to keep the stock look of the infowindow.  It seems doable... usually if I can tinker with something in the dev console, I can get to it with CSS, you know?

Comment: It's certainly doable, but because you can't be sure how google maps api will output those divs (in the same order), finding the div in question by index is very risky. You can't know for sure that it won't change.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle so I can play around a little? Or even a picure before and after.

Comment: http://palendar.us - search in san diego... there should be an event there.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941925/weird-glitch-image-on-google-maps-infowindow-with-bootstrap and this https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2410

Comment: Yeah, I could target all of the divs to fix the glitch.  Hell... I might try targeting all the divs to get a border-radius!

Comment: see below... baller =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#map {
  div[style*="z-index: 106"] * {
    @include border-radius( 4px );
  }
}
```

**BOOM!**

Comment: Indeed great solution. If you're using plain css and have multiple infowindows you can use:

`#map div[style*="z-index: 106"] > div {
 background-color:#f00 !important;
}`